# Understanding a Proof in COMBINATORICA 3 ( 3 - 4 ) (1983) 325--329

Tags: combinatorics

Preliminary words on notation:

1. $[n]$ denotes the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$.
2. For two vectors $x, y \in [k]^n$ we write $a(x, y) = h$ to denote that they agree on $h$ positions.
3. For some fixed $v \in [n]^k$ we denote by $g(v)$ the least amount of questions necessary to determine v if all questions are of the form "What is $a(v, q)$ for some question vector q?" and all questions are asked simultaneously.

In his proof on an upper bound on $g(v)$, Chvátal proposes the following sufficient condition on the amount of questions needed to determine $v$:

> Proof. By a difference pattern, we shall mean a nonempty set $I$ of subscripts along with two distinct colors $x_i$, $y_i$ for each $i \in I$; we shall say that this difference pattern
>   is split by a question $q$ if the number of subscripts $i \in I$ with $q_i \neq x_i$ differs from the number of subscripts $i \in I$ with $q_i \neq y_i$. Note that every two distinct candidates $x, y$ for the mystery vector $v$ define a unique difference pattern by $i \in I$ iff $x_i \neq y_i$, and
>   that this difference pattern is split by a question q **if and only if $a(q, x ) \neq a ( q , y)$**. Thus we **only need establish the existence of a set $Q$ of questions such that every difference pattern is split by some question in $Q$** ...

My two questions about this proof concern the two emphasized parts of the cited text:

1. Is the first assertion (i.e. ... **if and only if $a(q, x ) \neq a ( q , y)$** ...) true? Consider for example $x = [0 \, 1]$, $y = [1 \, 0]$, $I = \{2\}$ and $q = [1 \, 1]$. Certainly, by definition, we see that the subvectors induced by $I$ are split by $q$ as $x_2 = q_2 \neq y_2$. On the other hand we have $a(q, x) = 1 = a(q, y)$. This seems to contradict the author's claim, what did I miss?
2. I flat out fail to grasp the second assertion: Why does splitting every difference pattern imply that the set of questions $Q$ suffices to recover $v$?

Comment: something which may help is the term "Hamming distance". But also, if you are proving an upper bound on $g(v)$, what's wrong with $[n]^k$ has $n^k$ elements, and so by asking all $n^k$ questions simultaneously, there will be one and only one vector $q$ which has $a(v,q)=k$, which determines the vector $v$.

Comment: The wording of the author seems to suggest that this is about me missing some dead simple argument. Also about the bound: Sure, it works, but the one obtained by the author's line of thoughts is $\mathcal{O}(n / \log{n})$.

Comment: that is indeed better than my bound, i thought you just wanted **a** bound.

Comment: Well the difficulty lies precisely in arguing how to combine the information from different guesses; each guess $q$ and the following information $a(v, q)$ reduce the ambiguity but how much is enough?

Comment: Careful with your variables: Chvátal's bound is $O(n / \log n)$ for vectors from $[k]^n$, assuming fixed $k$.

Comment: You're right of course, I should have added that I was about a fixed value of $k$.

Comment: Actually my main point in that comment was $[n]^k$ vs $[k]^n$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have fixed the problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is the first assertion (i.e. ... **if and only if $a(q, x ) \neq a ( q , y)$** ...) true? Consider for example $x = [0 \, 1]$, $y = [1 \,
>    > 0]$, $I = \{2\}$

No.

> $x, y$ ... define a unique difference pattern by $i \in I$ iff $x_i \neq y_i$

If $x = [0 \, 1]$, $y = [1 \, 0]$ then $I = \{1, 2\}$.

The contributions to $a(q, x)$ and $a(q, y)$ of the indices not in $I$ are equal by definition of $I$.

---

> 2. I flat out fail to grasp the second assertion: Why does splitting every difference pattern imply that the set of questions $Q$ suffices
>      to recover $v$?

Suppose you cannot recover $v$. Without loss of generality we can select two distinct candidates $u$ and $w$ which are compatible with the answers given to $Q$. But by definition of $Q$ it contains a question $q$ which splits the difference pattern of $u$ and $w$, so they cannot both be compatible with the answers given to $Q$. Therefore by contradiction there are not two distinct candidates for $v$.

---

As an aside, the thing which I see as an error is (my emphasis)

> Note that every two distinct candidates $x, y$ for the mystery vector $v$ define a **unique** difference pattern by $i \in I$ iff $x_i \neq y_i$

This is trivially wrong, but it doesn't seem that the proof actually relies on it at all.

Comment: Dreadfully simple, as suspected.
I believe my "issue" with the first statement is somewhat similar to what you mention to be an error and has to do with a lack of clarity (at least to me) in the author's writing: It seems reasonable to think that the author is talking only about one direction, i.e., if $x_i \neq y_i$ for $i \in I$ then we get the desired (unique in the sense of "only one") difference pattern. On the other hand that pattern might of course results from various choices of $x$ and $y$ (i.e. unique not in the sense of bijections).

Comment: I did consider that interpretation of "*unique*", but in that case it's so obvious that $x, y, I$ completely define the difference pattern that it's completely superfluous. Ah well.